# Loading data piece by piece

Tags: java, android

I am developing android application which retrieves data from web (phpmyadmin). I can retrieve list of data and display as list items. However, I want to know how to retrieve and display data piece by piece. I mean 20 by 20.(Load 20 lists of items and when users scroll down it loads 20 lists of items again.) In database, about 60,000 rows of data are there. It takes a while to display the data on the app. So it would be great if you could provide any references or tutorials to me.

Comment: you have to implement this feature in your web service (backend) not in android.

Comment: Are you programming phpmyadmin? Unclear why you name phpmyadmin. Just make the right SELECT statement with a LIMIT.

Comment: You can check this https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore. It may help you.